# How to control the execution order of service installation and SQL script execution in InstallShield 2011 for a MSI installer project?

Tags: installation, installshield

I want to control the execution order of service installation/start and SQL script execution in InstallShield 2011 for a MSI installer project.

Right now first the windows service is installed and started by the setup. Afterwards the SQL scripts are executed. Since the windows service relies on the database created by the SQL scripts I would be great if the service is installed after the database was created.

Can I change the order of what is done by the MSI installer created by an InstallShield 2011 project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the Custom Actions and Sequences view in InstallShield provide this option. If that's the case, you should only tweak the sequence of those two actions. Alternatively, you always have a Direct Editor option where you can modify the MSI InstallExecuteSequence and InstallUISequence tables.

Comment: Note that to see the custom actions provided by InstallShield you may have to right-click the Custom Actions node and select Show All Actions. I think they show up in the sequence trees either way.